# can get a username and password match from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

as the title suggests I can get a match on password and username when trying to retrieve a user from my database.
When I first create a user I use this method that also hashes the password:

```
mysql_select_db($user);
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
function hash_password($password1, $username1) {
    return hash_hmac('sha512', $password1 . $username1, $site_key);
}
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO _SCD_BACKUP_USERS (username, password)
VALUES ('".$username."','".hash_password($password, $username)."')");
$r=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$r)echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();
mysql_close();`
```

this seems to work fine! To get what I want in the database. When I retrieve the info I can't get a match using this code:

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
function hash_password($password1, $username1) {
    return hash_hmac('sha512', $password1 . $username1, $site_key);
}
$encrypted = hash_password($username, $password);
$sql = 'SELECT username FROM _SCD_BACKUP_USERS WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
$result = $db -> query($sql, array($username, $encrypted));
if ($result -> numRows() < 1) {
    $arr = array('same' => true);
} else {
    $arr = array('same' => false);
}
print(json_encode($arr));
mysql_close();
```

Any suggestions?

//André

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are backwards

```
$encrypted = hash_password($username, $password);
```

should be

```
$encrypted = hash_password($password, $username);
```